# why are list appends not working in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

This code should be working without any problems, but it registers the first server i type .spam on and if i run it on another server it doesn't append the list but instead changes the first server id to the last one

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.spam'):
        global thislist
        thislist = [1, 3]
        thislist.append(message.guild.id)
        print(thislist)
        print(len(thislist))
    if message.content.startswith('.stop'):
        global s
        s = str(message.guild.id)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

any help would be appreciated

The complete code:

```
import discord, pyautogui, time
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.spam'):
        global thislist
        thislist = [message.guild.id]
        print(thislist)
        print(len(thislist))
    if message.content.startswith('.stop'):
        global s
        s = str(message.guild.id)
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('discordpy')
async def spam(ctx, *, my_id):
    print("it worked")
    time.sleep(5)
    x = 1
    y = 0
    global z
    z = 0


    while y != 1:
        if z == 1:
            z = 0
            break
        myid = str(my_id)
        await ctx.channel.send(myid + " x " +str(x))
        print(x)
        x += 1
        print(y)
        time.sleep(0.5)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('discordpy')
async def stop(ctx):
    for x in thislist:
        print(thislist)
        if x == s:
            global z
            z = 1



@client.command()
@commands.has_role('discordpy')
async def stopbot(ctx):
    self.isrunning = False






client.run('token')
```

dsakfjasdfkajsdfikcmedksnjedkjnfskdjnfcjsdjkfkszidfnzsjkeudfnhszjwedfhnzsjkdefnkzsdxjfnzswdxfnwxnzksxdjnfwszexznswexnjdsnhjsdn

Comment: Why are you using `append`? Just write `thislist = [1, 3, message.guild.id]`

Comment: BigBrain, i'll try it out tho

Comment: same thing, i want it to append guild id's of every server i type .spam on

Comment: do you have discord?

Comment: I used Discord a few years ago, but not recently, and I've never scripted it.

Comment: What do you want to append it to? When you assign `thislist = [1, 3]` you're replacing the list contents, not appending.

Comment: well alright in that case, but it ain't working

Comment: how do i append it then

Comment: wait a sec, i'll give the complete code

Comment: Just use `thislist.append(something)` without assigning first.

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to the list, assign the initial value outside the function, and then just append in the function.

If you assign to the list in the function, all the previous elements are discarded.

```
thislist = [1, 3]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.spam'):
        thislist.append(message.guild.id)
        print(thislist)
        print(len(thislist))
    if message.content.startswith('.stop'):
        global s
        s = str(message.guild.id)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: sure thing, i'll give it a try

Comment: omg, thanks a lot. it worked i've been trying to fix this shit frm the past few hours. Thanks so much